# How to access HTML control value whose id contains % in it. e.g. ABN%

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to remove div whose id is ABN%_divMetricMain, I am writing the following line of code but its not working any solution?

```
$("div[id$=" + code + "_divMetricMain]").remove();  //code=ABN%
```

I got the solution and I am sharing it with all of you:

```
if ($("input[id$=metricId]:contains('%')"))   \\code=metricId which is ABN% 
{
                        var code = code.replace("%", "\\%");
                        $("div[id$=" + code + "_divMetricMain]").remove();
}
```

The reason is to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \
[Link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for refrence.

Comment: And why there is `%` in ID ?

Comment: any solution rather editing? @Tushar Gupta

Comment: Because its code and its description is rate in percentage

Answer (score 0):

try using [attribute contains * selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
  $("div[id*=" + code + "_divMetricMain]")
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Example**](http://jsbin.com/EcuQEQi/2/edit) :

`$("div[id*='a%']").css('background-color','red')` // you should do remove instead of css.

so for :

```
<body>
  <div id='a%2'>a</div>
  <div id='a3'>a1</div>
  <div id='a%6'>a2</div>
  <div id='a2'>a3</div>
  <div id='a%5'>a4</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: @MuhammadHisham it was just an example  just do this `$("div[id*='%']")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the actual "=" selector, also put a single quote around your id.

```
$("div[id='" + code + "_divMetricMain']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day I got the solution and I am sharing it with all of you:

```
if ($("input[id$=metricId]:contains('%')"))   \\code=metricId which is ABN% 
{
                        var code = code.replace("%", "\\%");
                        $("div[id$=" + code + "_divMetricMain]").remove();
}
```

The reason is to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \ 
[Link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for refrence.